# TypeScript: cannot seem to understand this generics usage for promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, promise

Here is a function, which takes a promise and a number which is for timeout and returns another promise. If the promise as the first argument doesn't resolve before the timeout, the promise returned from the function will reject immediately. Or it will resolve the value when the first promise resolves.

```
function resolveOrTimeout<T>(promise: Promise<T>, timeout: number): Promise<T> {
  return new Promise<T>((resolve, reject) => {
    // start the timeout, reject when it triggers
    const task = setTimeout(() => reject("time up!"), timeout);

    promise.then(val => {
      // cancel the timeout
      clearTimeout(task);

      // resolve with the value
      resolve(val);
    });
  });
}
resolveOrTimeout(fetch(""), 3000);
```

I understand the logic of the function and I am well aware of how promise works in JavaScript. But I just don't understand the type annotations here, specifically the usage of generics here. I understand that generics parameterize types like functions parameterize value, but here why do we need to parameterize the types in the first place? And also why is that even the function call doesn't provide the type variables as the `T` in the generics, the compiler doesn't report any errors?

Answer (score 2):

A Promise isn't really interesting by itself, any more than an empty Array is interesting by itself. It's just a placeholder for an eventual value, a box to contain, and that value has a type. We could write the same function 15 times for various types that can go in the box, or we can say to the compiler that either the caller provides the type, or it *can try to infer the type from usage*.

To give the intuition, let's write a function that returns the last element of an array, first in plain JS:

```
function last(arr) {
  return arr[arr.length - 1];
}
```

and add the types:

```
function last<T>(arr: T[]): T {
  return arr[arr.length - 1];
}
```

We don't really care *what* the type is, and we want this to work for arrays of all sorts of things:

```
const x = last(['a', 'b']); // compiler can infer x is a string
const y = last([1, 2]);     // compiler can infer y is a number
const z = last<number>(['a', 3]); // heterogenous array, explicit
```

Nobody wants to sit and write out overloads for all the different things that can go in an array, so... yeah generics FTW.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I think I get it why we use generics but I still don't quite how it is going to help us get type safety. Like your example with the `last` function. Without using generics we can still make sure that the arguments got passed in is an array right? Did you mean that the usage of Generics here is just to get the benefit of type inferences during the development?

Comment: @Joji hmmm, I think the problem is that you are thinking that an array and a promise are types themselves. And they are but... it's maybe more useful to think of them as *incomplete*. The type safety we care about preserving is knowing what the type of the thing we're pulling out of the container is. So if we have `number[]` we want to be able to safely pull out an item and know it's a number. Same for Promises: Promise is an incomplete type and we want to complete it and have `Promise<number>`, or whatever. But sometimes we want to have the same behavior across multiple types: the array...

Comment: operations like my example of `last` are the same for `number[]` as they are for `string[]`. So you can either write an overload for number, and another for string, and another for each other type that you want to 'complete' array with, or you can use a generic type that receives a concrete type on use (N.B. we're still talking about compile time). So when the compiler sees `last(someArr)` where it knows that `someArr` is type `number[]` then type variable `T` gets the concrete type number and it knows the type of the return value from the function must be number.

Comment: Golang for example lacks this feature: pulling an item out of an array of unknown type or the base type requires an unsafe cast to give it a concrete type because Go lacks generics. Or such was the case when last I looked at it a couple of years ago, admittedly that's a loooong time in terms of a youngish language under heavy development.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! That was clear! One last question, what does N.B. mean?

Comment: @Joji [Nota Bene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nota_bene). If the answer works for you please accept :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, generic type parameter you pass to `Promise` is the type that it will provide when it resolves.

A simple example:

```
function numberInThreeSeconds(): Promise<number> {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(123), 3000)
        //                       ^ generic paramter type passed to Promise
    })
}
```

---

So, given that...

> "I understand that generics parameterize types like functions parameterize value, but here why do we need to parameterize the types in the first place?"

You do that so the resolved value of `resolveOrTimeout` has a known type.

```
resolveOrTimeout(numberInThreeSeconds(), 5000)
  .then(val => console.log(val * 2)) // val is known to be of type number
```

Because `numberInThreeSeconds` is known to resolve to a `number`, then the usage of generics allows the function to return a promise that resolves to the same type as its first argument.

---

> "And also why is that even the function call doesn't provide the type variables as the T in the generics, the compiler doesn't report any errors?"

Because generic functions can *infer* their generic parameters from usage. At it's simplest:

```
function identity<T>(arg: T): T { return arg }
const a = identity('abc') // string
const b = identity(123) // number
```

Because typescript knows the type of the argument, it can infer `T` as whatever that type is, and then it returns that same type `T`.

So the same thing is happening with `resolveOrTimeout<T>`.

```
function resolveOrTimeout<T>(promise: Promise<T>, timeout: number): Promise<T> {}
```

The arg `promise: Promise<T>` tells typescript that it can infer `T` by requiring that the argument be a promise, and then looking inside that promise to find its resolved type.

And it can now return `Promise<T>` as well, which says that this function returns a promise that resolves to the same type as the `promise` argument.

---

[Additional reading on how generics and generics inference work here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)

Answer (score -1):

In this case, the generic `T` isn't really useful indeed. However, assume we change the code to this:

```
function resolveOrTimeout<T>(promise: Promise<T>, timeout: T): Promise<T> {
}
```

When given an input, the compiler will understand that the output of this function will be a promise of the type of the parameter `timout`. This helps writing code that is typesafe, but can be written more "generic"

A generic is used if the type of the value is not important for the context. For example, say we crate a function that puts the generic parameter in an array. We won't need the type of this parameter, since we only put it in an array. With the generic we can tell typescript that this function accepts some sort of parameter, and the output will be an array of the same type.

```
function toArray(input: T): T[] {
    return [input];
}
```

At compile time, the compiler will figure this out. The code below will result in an error saying that `toArray` returns an `string[]`, but the variable is expecting an `numer[]`

```
let someArray: number[] = toArray("Some string")
```

Comment: Why would `timeout` be a `T`? That's the number of milliseconds passed to `setTimeout`, so it must be a number.

Comment: Yeah this example doesn't really make sense if you add the original code of the TS. That's why I let the function body empty